# Get the first object from the response body

Tags: mysql, angularjs, arrays

I am using Angular $http get method for get results from mysql database it returns 3 rows i am sending these results from the server side using method

```
res.json(results);
```

and on client side i console these results it show results Array[3] which contains 3 objects i use the

now i tried 2 different methods to display each object separately

```
console.log(response[0]);
console.log(response.data[0]);
```

but it always show Array[3]

i need to get each element separately and store it in array 
response structure is

```
>Array[3]
 0:object
 ID:1
 Name:"xyz"

>__proto__:object
1:object
ID:2
Name:"abc"
```

i need to get first object and store it in Array

Comment: You could loop on `response.data` and you will get each element of an Array.

Comment: can i use response.get(0); ? and so on @Pankaj Parker

Comment: You could do something like this `angular.forEach(response.data, function(element){ console.log("Current element", element); //you could do operation on elements of an array here })`

Comment: Could you post the json trace?

Comment: I try this but its not working

Comment: I post my response body structure @Pablo